# listview wih item click listener fetch wrong data in searchview

Tags: android, firebase, android-listview, searchview

when i fetch data from firebase to listview with a itemclicklistener and its working fine,

But when i add a searchview to the listview, Searchview will fetch the itementer image description here but the itemclicklistener showing a wrong result (its showing its position), Please help.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btMenu = findViewById(R.id.btMenu);

    sr_txt = findViewById(R.id.sr_txt);
    listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("dreamapp");
    dream1 = new Dream();
    title_list = new ArrayList<>();
    answer_list = new ArrayList<>();


    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,R.layout.item,R.id.item,title_list);
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot d:snapshot.getChildren())
            {
                dream1 = d.getValue(Dream.class);
                title_list.add(dream1.getTitle());
                answer_list.add(dream1.getAnswer());
            }



            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i,long id) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, answer.class);
                    String p=answer_list.get(i);
                    intent.putExtra("answer",p);
                    startActivity(intent);



                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });


    sr_txt.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            MainActivity.this.arrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            MainActivity.this.arrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);

            return false;
        }
    });


}
```

And i have passed the answerlist values from firebase to another intent which is given below , where the result is fetching as position number from database which i need as itemsposition.

package com.example.dreamapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class answer extends AppCompatActivity {

```
TextView textView1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_answer);

    textView1 = findViewById(R.id.answertext);
    
    String answertxt = getIntent().getStringExtra("answer");
    textView1.setText(answertxt);


}
```

}

Comment: Can you try to comment `MainActivity.this.arrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);` ?

Comment: I have given this in the searchView  sr_txt. SetOnQueryTextListener   and the search is working,  it list the result from listview, but on the onclicklistener its not working, it gives me the position of listview not item's position.

Comment: Of course it will give you the position of item in listView!  If you need some identifiers you have to add the field in your Object throught which you can understand what item it is

Comment: can you explain bit more?

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have found the solution for this, When i added one more arrayadapter and listview , then i used it it in the searchview then it worked, it get the results if i search the exact words in it,

```
 sr_txt.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            MainActivity.this.arrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
            MainActivity.this.arrayAdapter2.getFilter().filter(query);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            MainActivity.this.arrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            MainActivity.this.arrayAdapter2.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

And SearchView

```
 sr_txt.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            MainActivity.this.arrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
            MainActivity.this.arrayAdapter2.getFilter().filter(query);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            MainActivity.this.arrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            MainActivity.this.arrayAdapter2.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

But still i face an issue with searchView, When i search it searches the entire characters from the array, i need a solution if i could search only five characters from it , it will work fine.